# Monero privacy features different from coin shuffling used in nxt/ardor?

Tags: ringct, privacy, cryptocurrency-comparison

How are Monero privacy features different from coin shuffling used in nxt/ardor? https://nxtwiki.org/wiki/Coin_Shuffling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CoinShuffle is a form of decentralized mixing. For simplicity's sake, you can consider it similar to CoinJoin. You can read the academic paper on CoinShuffle [here](http://crypsys.mmci.uni-saarland.de/projects/CoinShuffle/coinshuffle.pdf).

A mixing approach has significant shortfalls compared to Monero's ring signature scheme:

1. Users must communicate with each other. With Monero, you can include other users' outputs in your ring signature without any active communication.
2. You must wait for these mixing transactions to be completed. This may take a while for a large number of funds.
3. It is voluntary, so the entropy set of people participating in CoinShuffle is small. With Monero, every transaction contributes to the entropy set.
4. Transacted amounts are still visible. With Monero, transaction amounts are hidden.